# Stack two borders with drop-shadows?

Tags: html, css, web, dropshadow

How could I wrap a border around another border and have them both use inset drop-shadows (like double matting in a picture frame)?

Comment: Got a picture of how you want this to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the [`:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#before-and-after). See jsFiddle demos at end of answer.

### HTML

```
<div class="frame"><img src="../img/logo.png"></div>
```

### CSS

```css
.frame {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    margin:20px;
    z-index:5;
    padding:10px;
    background:#376b90;
}
.frame:before {
    position:absolute;
    content:".";
    display:block;
    font-size:0;
    color:transparent;
    /* Change left, right, top, bottom, and box-shadow to position */
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px 2px black;
}
.frame:after {
    position:absolute;
    content:".";
    display:block;
    font-size:0;
    color:transparent;
    /* Change left, right, top, bottom, and box-shadow to position */
    left:5px;
    top:5px;
    right:5px;
    bottom:5px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px 2px black;
}
```

### Example Usage

- [Both shadows *outside*](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuNZE/)
- [One shadow *inside*, one shadow *outside*](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuNZE/1/)
- [Both shadows *inside*](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuNZE/2/)
- [Two inset shadows, one outset shadow, and custom background](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuNZE/7/) - *Requested by OP*
- [Inset borders](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuNZE/4/) - *Replicating https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904061/526741*
- [Variable length content](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuNZE/8/)

Answer (score 1):

[Here are my fiddle's on the topic](http://jsfiddle.net/rockinthesixstring/3rRWq/)

---

### OPTION 1)

You can use Pseudo Classes to accomplish this

#### Html

```
<span class="doubleMatt">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
</span>
```

#### CSS

```
span,img{padding:0;margin:0;border:0;}
.doubleMatt{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
}

.doubleMatt:after{
    position:absolute;
    top:1px;
    left:1px;
    bottom:1px;
    right:1px;
    border:4px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    outline:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    content:" ";
}​
```

---

### OPTION 2)

You can use some basic (one dimensional) goodness

#### CSS

```
.basicMatt {
    background:#222;
    padding:3px;
    border:3px solid #666;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<img class="basicMatt" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
```

---

### OPTION 3)

you can use an Outline

#### CSS

```
.outlinedMatt{
    background:#fff;
    padding:8px;
    border:3px solid #222;
    outline:3px solid #666;
    margin:3px;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<img class="outlinedMatt" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/200" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you could nest the divs as shown in - http://jsfiddle.net/nG4Td/2/

```
<div class="border">
  <div class="border2">
    <p>hello world</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.border{
  border: 5px inset black;
  background:#ccc;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  padding:20px;    
}
.border2{
  border: 5px inset black;
  background:#eee;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  padding:20px;    
 }`
```

Comment: I edited yours a bit and now it's exactly what I had in mind: http://jsfiddle.net/nG4Td/3/  Thanks!

Comment: @redleaf, do you have browser requirements that my answer didn't meet? Using my technique, the same exact effect can be accomplished without adding additional HTML wrappers (see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuNZE/3/)). And it should be noted my example doesn't rely on static `width`/`height` values, and it has consistent spacing on all sides (unlike this answer).

Comment: @bfrohs How can I change yours to be white without blocking the center content?

Comment: @redleaf, what are you trying to change to white?

Comment: @bfrohs all three areas of the box.  Currently it's transparent, and changing the color to white did not remove the transparency: http://jsfiddle.net/ZuNZE/5/

Comment: @redleaf, just have to adjust the positioning of each of the pseudo-elements: http://jsfiddle.net/ZuNZE/7/

Comment: @redleaf, my answer also supports variable sized content: [mine](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuNZE/8/) vs [yours](http://jsfiddle.net/nG4Td/5/).

Comment: @bfrohs variable sizing is just what I needed - I'm going with yours.